# grab substring in pandas series

Tags: string, pandas, filtering

I have a dataframe df with X columns.
I want to fill  df['date'] and df['time'] with a substring located inside the column df['job.filename'].
I tried to convert the Series into list and then grab list[x:y]=date and also

`for i,row in df.iterrows():
    df.set_value(i,'time',row['job.filename'][-10:-4])
    df.set_value(i,'date',row['job.filename'][21:27])`

But this didn't work
Cheers

Comment: Can you post a snippet of job.file and what part of the substring do you need extracted?

Comment: df['job.filename][0] ='IMAT list 1-3609-0-20161214-092934.csv'. I want to use the 6 and 8 digits numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took your sample job.filename to create a dataframe and tried the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['IMAT list 1-3609-0-20161214-092934.csv'])
df['date'] = df[0].str.extract('.*-\d+-(\d+)-\d+') #0 is the column name, in your case job.filename
df['time'] = df[0].str.extract('.*-\d+-\d+-(\d+)')
```

You get:

```
 0                                      date        time
```

0   IMAT list 1-3609-0-20161214-092934.csv  20161214    092934

This regex will work only if all the values follow the exact pattern

Comment: I receive Attribute error : DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'

Comment: On which line? Can you exactly put that?

Comment: My bad, the format had been modifed ealier in my code by datetime. It works, however the two lines give me the date. What is this notation '('.*-\d+-\d+-(\d+)')? Where can I find documentation?

Comment: Are you getting date in both instead of date and time?

Comment: The expression inside the bracket is python regex. It's a powerful string extraction tool. You can read about it.